# Can I Do my wedding after 2 deaths in the family on both my fiancé and my side?

Tags: scripture, rituals, marriage, death

I’m a Hindu and so is my fiancé.

Last year I got proposed to and then my fiancé grandma(maternal) died a week later. Around September.

She lives in her home country while we live in a different one.

We did all the religious work and We waited a year to do an engagement.

After my engagement my grandma(maternal) died 2 months later. She lived in the same country as us. Then a month and a half later my fiancé grandfather(paternal) dies (different country).

We have our wedding set for 6 months later.

The date has been set for a year now. I was wondering if we need to cancel and wait A whole year to do my wedding since they were 2 deaths on both sides and 1 after I got proposed to.

Is this a sign or should I continue my wedding?

Another thing to add is that my fiancé grandfather wasn’t in contact with none of his children.

They have no love for him as he treated them bad. He never went to my fiancé father's wedding or any of his children.

So I really don’t know what to do, everyone says continue with the wedding but there has been 2 deaths in a row and “close family”.

I know my grandma would want the wedding to continue but then again is this a sign.

I just don’t want anything bad to happen when we get married.